# How do I proxy based on MIME type?

Tags: apache-2.4, php-fpm, mod-proxy, mime-type

How do I proxy a file in Apache based on its MIME type? I want to use PHP-FPM with FastCGI but the recommended solution using `ProxyPassMatch` is clunky, a pain to work with, and all around unfavorable. How would I go about proxying based on MIME type instead?

Comment: It is not clunky, why do you say that? You just need to use PCRE to specify what you want to pass onto fpm.

Comment: @ezra-s I find it clunky mainly because you can't force a folder as `text/plain` to not process the PHP.

Comment: I don't follow, proxypassmatch is used to specify paths/uri with regex, not mime/types.

Comment: @ezra-s The wiki recommends proxypassmatch, but I don't want to use proxypassmatch.

Comment: well, see the handler answer I gave you earlier.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the handler method (2.4.10 onwards):

```
<FilesMatch \.php>
    SetHandler  "proxy:unix:/path/to/app.sock|fcgi://localhost/"
</FilesMatch>
```